# Metallic materials not working in Forge Model Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have models saved in .gltf format and I am trying to display them using Autodesk Viewer. I managed to upload them to a bucket and translate them to svf format using the translate job. I also setup a server running the model viewer. I did everything according to the tutorials provided in the documentation.

However the models use reflective, metallic surfaces but for some reason they show as flat colors inside the viewer. I have tried using some demo models provided by Autodesk to check if the error was inside the viewer however those displayed reflective surfaces with no problem. My suspicion that it has something to do with Autodesk Model Derivative translate functionality.

If anyone encountered the same problem and found a solution and can give me some pointers where I might be doing something wrong I would be thankful. [Model shown in windows model viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UksR9.jpg) [The same model displayed in Autodesk Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94l9j.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is because the Forge Model Derivative service supports glTF version [1.0](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/specification/1.0), and not the current version [2.0](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/specification/2.0).

The translation services focuses on common AEC/manufacturing design formats such as DWG, RVT, or IFC.

One thing you *could* try is converting your glTF 2.0 assets to FBX, and then uploading the FBX to Forge instead. The materials might be persisted better with this pipeline.